# Unit testing for an old app - Which components should be considers first?

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I'm currently working on over-4-year-old project (iOS - with MVC design), which has been passed through many various developers. For years it has been developed in an as-long-as-it-works-its-ok manner. Now out of the blue my client asked to add Unit Testing to the project, and I really don't know where to start with the project.

Can any one suggest a good start point? I mean which class (view controllers, models, utilities) should I write the test cases first?

Comment: I think this is a pretty opinionated question unless you can edit your question provide more detail.  I think it's definitely good to take a step back and really think about where to start in an objective way.  Can you tell us more about the app, what is the most mission-critical part of the app, are the models just plain models or do they have something more?  How easy is it to refactor these parts of the app?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm in kind of a Massive View Controller situation, in my app there is a main VC, which consists of several child view controllers, each is as equally important as the others. Another problem is the child view controllers are coupled together. Now I just need an advice from someone who was involved in the same situation, even a general suggestion is enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code base it's hard to say, but I would start with the utilities classes first, refactor them to make them testable (where known inputs will produce known outputs), then begin adding unit tests.
As you do new development (add new features, fix bugs, etc.), make sure you make tests for the work you did, this way your number of tests keeps going up and after a while you will have some pretty good coverage.